# Filtering an array with large number of Items in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, filter

I'm trying to implement search in a tableview by filter an array with more than 3000 items, and as expected the result is a very slow search(The letters appear in the search field seconds after the key is pressed). Any suggestions on how to make search faster?

I've tried using `filteredClips.filter { $0.text?.range(of: searchField.stringValue, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .anchored ]) != nil }` but its the same result as the code below.

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
     let searchText = searchField.stringValue.lowercased()
     let searchResults = filteredClips.filter {($0.text?.lowercased().contains(searchText))!
           || ($0.desc != nil && 
($0.desc?.lowercased().contains(searchField.stringValue.lowercased()))!)}

     filteredClips = searchResults
     clipsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Note: I think the slow text typing mentioned above is due wait for `controlTextDidChange` to complete every time. Is it possible to continue character insertion without waiting for `controlTextDidChange` to complete for each character?

Comment: Is your collection lexicographically sorted?

Comment: You could filter based on the first letter the user enters, then save all the matches in a new array. Then when the user enters a second letter, just filter through the (now much smaller) array, and save the results in yet another (even smaller) array. This will be much faster.

Comment: @LeoDabus no, they are not. It's in order in which the items where added.

Comment: @Eric33187 if a user were to delete a letter wouldn't the same smaller array be filtered.

Comment: @unknown If the user deletes a letter, you should take the previous array which is already sorted. You have to keep track of the arrays as the user types. All in all, you'll basically need to detect if the user has added or deleted a letter, and take the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 0):

You should use textfield delegate and try search by each character user entered by user.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let text = (searchText.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let count = text.count
        if count > 1
        {
            searchList = searchText.text!.isEmpty ? searchList : searchList.filter({(searchListTitle: searchListDataModel) -> Bool in
                // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
                return searchListTitle.title?.range(of: searchText.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            return true
        } else {
            tableViewList = searchList
            tableView.reloadData()
            return true
        }
        
    }
```